# Google Tango : Aligning the ADF frame to the Color Frame

Tags: augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I am trying to create a Unity Augmented Reality Application that works of the pose determined by the ADF localization. I add the camera feed to the "Persistent State" demo, but my ADF localized frame does not align with the camera feed. The ground always seems to be transformed to be above the horizon.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I've found a solution. The problem is that in the PoseController script, the horizon is not set correctly with the real world horizon, but in the AugmentedReality example it is done correctly (in the ARScreen script). So in my AR application things looked like they moved up as i moved far away from them.

To fix this, you can either start your application inside the AugmentedReality example as Guillaume said or make the next changes in the PoseController scripts:

-First of all we have the matrix `m_matrixdTuc` which is initialized as follows:

```
    m_matrixdTuc = new Matrix4x4();
    m_matrixdTuc.SetColumn(0, new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    m_matrixdTuc.SetColumn(1, new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    m_matrixdTuc.SetColumn(2, new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
    m_matrixdTuc.SetColumn(3, new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

Well, we must rename it as `m_matrixcTuc` and change the -1.0f value:

```
    m_matrixcTuc = new Matrix4x4();
    m_matrixcTuc.SetColumn(0, new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    m_matrixcTuc.SetColumn(1, new Vector4(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    m_matrixcTuc.SetColumn(2, new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    m_matrixcTuc.SetColumn(3, new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

This is because we're not gonna use this matrix directly to get the transform of the camera but we're gonna make some operations before to get the true `m_matrixdTuc`.

-2nd, we must initialize this three variables:

```
private Matrix4x4 m_matrixdTuc;


// Device frame with respect to IMU frame.
private Matrix4x4 m_imuTd;

// Color camera frame with respect to IMU frame.
private Matrix4x4 m_imuTc;
```

(the true `m_matrixdTuc` and the other 2 are gotten from the ARScreen script)

-3rd we need the `_SetCameraExtrinsics` method from ARScreen:

```
/// <summary>
/// The function is for querying the camera extrinsic, for example: the transformation between
/// IMU and device frame. These extrinsics is used to transform the pose from the color camera frame
/// to the device frame. Because the extrinsic is being queried using the GetPoseAtTime()
/// with a desired frame pair, it can only be queried after the ConnectToService() is called.
///
/// The device with respect to IMU frame is not directly queryable from API, so we use the IMU
/// frame as a temporary value to get the device frame with respect to IMU frame.
/// </summary>
private void _SetCameraExtrinsics()
{
    double timestamp = 0.0;
    TangoCoordinateFramePair pair;
    TangoPoseData poseData = new TangoPoseData();

    // Getting the transformation of device frame with respect to IMU frame.
    pair.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU;
    pair.targetFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
    PoseProvider.GetPoseAtTime(poseData, timestamp, pair);
    Vector3 position = new Vector3((float)poseData.translation[0],
                                   (float)poseData.translation[1],
                                   (float)poseData.translation[2]);
    Quaternion quat = new Quaternion((float)poseData.orientation[0],
                                     (float)poseData.orientation[1],
                                     (float)poseData.orientation[2],
                                     (float)poseData.orientation[3]);
    m_imuTd = Matrix4x4.TRS(position, quat, new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

    // Getting the transformation of IMU frame with respect to color camera frame.
    pair.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU;
    pair.targetFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR;
    PoseProvider.GetPoseAtTime(poseData, timestamp, pair);
    position = new Vector3((float)poseData.translation[0],
                           (float)poseData.translation[1],
                           (float)poseData.translation[2]);
    quat = new Quaternion((float)poseData.orientation[0],
                          (float)poseData.orientation[1],
                          (float)poseData.orientation[2],
                          (float)poseData.orientation[3]);
    m_imuTc = Matrix4x4.TRS(position, quat, new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    m_matrixdTuc = Matrix4x4.Inverse(m_imuTd) * m_imuTc * m_matrixcTuc;
}
```

Now as you can see, we get the true value of the `m_matrixdTuc` variable that will be used in the `OnTangoPoseAvailable` method.

I don't really understand the maths behind this methods but I've found that it works perfectly on my application. Hope it works for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

I already tried something similar. If I understand well, the objects you add to be augmented are rotated toward the top of the screen, and this is especially visible when they are far, as they look like lifted upward.

To make it work, I simply started my project inside the Experimental Augmented Reality app with the "red map marker": there, the camera feed is already aligned to the world properly.